# Pulling data from DB via AJAX and CakePHP 2.x

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am working on a re-commerce site that gathers information about used cellphones from the user via Javascript/jQuery.

I am trying to figure out how I can create a proper method in my QuotesController that will allow me to: 
1) Call it using an AJAX "post" using jQuery/AJAX
2) Return the quote data, so I can display the price to the user

Here's what I have so far:
jQuery function call:

```
var data =
    {
        device_id: quote['device_id'], 
        carrier_id: quote['carrier_id'], 
        condition_id: quote['condition_id'], 
        size: quote['size']
    };

    // Pull quote using AJAX
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/c4c/quotes/get_quote",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('success');
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            $('#quote').html(jqXHR.responseText);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error');
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            $('#quote').html(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Method in QuotesController:

```
        // Gets a quote's price via ajax
    public function get_quote(){
    $this->layout = 'ajax';

    $device_id = $this->request->data['device_id'];
    $carrier_id = $this->request->data['carrier_id'];
    $condition_id = $this->request->data['condition_id'];
    $size = $this->request->data['size'];

    // Get quote
    $quote = $this->Quote->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Quote.device_id'=>$device_id,
                                                                   'Quote.carrier_id'=>$carrier_id,
                                                                   'Quote.condition_id'=>$condition_id,
                                                                   'Quote.size'=>$size,
                                                                    )));

    $this->set('quote',$quote);

    //$this->render('get_quote');
    return json_encode($quote);
}
```

I keep getting errors, so I know what I am doing is wrong, but I can't seem to find any answers on CakePHP's site, nor via Google.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A quick-fix for your situation would be:

Firstly do not do `return json_encode($quote);` - create a view file for the ajax response. It should be located in: `App/View/Quotes/Ajax/get_quote.ctp`.

Then set the response variable: 
`$this->set('quote', $quote);`

You also need to set some headers because the default ajax layout I suspect you're using is just an empty layout. Create a layout file in: `App/View/layouts/ajax.ctp`

You can do this with the basic PHP `header()` function:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $content_for_layout;
```

The Cache-control header is there so that there is no cache whatsoever for ajax data.
If you're using a request/response monitoring tool (which you should be doing) you'll notice that now it directly identifies the response as JSON.
Then in your view you can:

```
echo json_encode($quote);
```

This should solve you're case, based on the scarce information you provided, but how 'is it best to do json/ajax' in CakePHP? Here are a few steps.

1. Use [Router::parseExtensions();](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions) to easily identify what request is coming in via:
2. Check what's coming in with the [RequestHandlerComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html)'s isXml() (or is('ajax')) methods
3. Use data views ([JSON and XML views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)) for the response rendering. You actually have two choises here - use [data views with the serialize key](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key) or use [data view with view files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-view-files). The choice is up to you.
4. Use a central ajax layout, and set any headers you like with `RequestHandlerComponent::setContent($name, $type = null)` - [take a look here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#responding-to-requests).
   Note that setContent() should be called in the beforeFilter() of your controller.